# Linq To Sql left join using multiple join clauses

Tags: vb.net, linq

For some reason I am getting a syntax error on the below code. What I am trying to achieve is
A LEFT JOIN with MULTIPLE JOIN CLAUSES. The syntax error occurs at the Keyword INTO foobar. VS 2012 says unexpected Token. Any help would be great, thank you !

```
 Dim results = From f In foo _
                   Join b In bar On new with {f.Type,f.ID} Equals New With {"Test",b.ID} into fooBar _
                   from x in foobar.DefaultEmpty() _ 
                   Where foo.id = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a [`Group Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531303.aspx):

```
Dim results = From f In foo _
               Group Join b In bar On 
                   New With {f.Type,f.ID} Equals New With {"Test",b.ID} _
                   Into fooBar = Group _
               from x in foobar.DefaultEmpty() _ 
               Where foo.id = 1
```

Comment: @D Stanley, why would the have a Group Join msdn says it does the same thing as a left join. What is the difference and why does it work for me?

Comment: @gh9 That's the syntax VB uses - it has some other uses besides the _equivalent_ of a `LEFT JOIN` (such as being able to select aggregates of the right hand side) so I guess they chose a more generic syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast the `f.ID` or `b.ID`

```
 Dim results = From f In foo _
                   Join b In bar On new with {f.Type, CInt(f.ID)} Equals New With {"Test", CInt(b.ID)} into fooBar _
                   from x in foobar.DefaultEmpty() _ 
                   Where foo.id = 1
```

Comment: @ still get the unexpected token error right before INTO keyword